# RBAC User Management GUI Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Is there a module/component/extension where users,permissions and roles can be created and then a role can be assigned to a user via GUI/web-page instead of writing code ?

I want all this info to be stored in database i.e. users/roles/permissions.

Comment: any updates to a good yii2 gui for RBAC?

Comment: I found this module, worked for me: https://github.com/webvimark/user-management

Answer (score 3):

You can use this module [yii2-admin](https://github.com/mdmsoft/yii2-admin)

Comment: I have checked this module but there is no way to assign role to a user via GUI ? If you can guide please.

Answer (score 3):

I found out a module https://github.com/webvimark/user-management
which allows to create users, permissions, roles etc and also allows role assignment via web interface. Roles can be assigned using the column saying: **Roles and Permissions**, to users on the user listing page of this module :)

[Users Listing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aQZx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Yii2    [advanced application template](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-advanced-app.html)  provides a specific component for these aspectt,  you can find it in the directory vendor / yiisoft / yii2 / rbac you can find the basic components including the migration to generate the appropriate database tables.
At this point with gii should not be difficult to develop a user interface suited to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/amnah/yii2-user

A little late to the party but this one has worked for me. It has a GUI for managing roles, email sign-up, password reset, etc.  I've modified it for my own purposes by moving it to a dedicated module, rather than using the vendor extension managed by composer. There are instructions included on how to do that.

It hasn't been updated in a while though